# Direct calculation of flux in 3D

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question;
What is the flux of the vector field $F=<x,-y,z>$ out through the surface of the cylinder which is $x^{2} + y^2 = a^2 , 0<z<b$.

I can easily find the answer by divergence theorem but when I try to direct calculation of the flux through the surface , I find 0.Am I doing some algebra mistakes or do I miss anything different ?

My path;

$$\int \int <x,-y,z>.\frac{<x,y,0>}{a} dS \\
x=a*cos\theta \\
y=a*sin\theta \\
\int_0^b \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{a^2 *cos2\theta}{a}*a*d\theta dz \\
$$

Comment: What is F? And you have given the equation of a circle and mentioned 3D flux.

Comment: Why don't you post your working for the direct calculation so we can _see_ where the mistake(s) lie.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat corrected.

Comment: @Mattos I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integration over divergence is correct and it is $\pi b a^2$

The integration on surface is correct except for mission the top and the bottom of the cylinder!

$$\int \vec F .d \vec S= \text{flux around} + \text{flux top} + \text{flux bottom}=\\\iint (x,-y,z).(\frac x a,\frac y a,0) dS+\iint (x,-y,b).(0,0,1)dS+\iint (x,-y,0).(0,0,-1)dS\\ =\pi b a^2$$

Using divergence:

$$\vec \nabla . \vec F=1$$

$$\iiint (\vec \nabla . \vec F) dV=V=\pi b a^2$$

Comment: @Arasgium Thanks for your answer.By the way , for the bottom part $\vec{F}=<x,-y,0>$